# How to call a class on listview's item

Tags: android

Hi I am creating an application in which i am showing a list view on click of a tab button.
I want to know how to call a class after clicking an item in list

Answer (score 1):

Use setOnItemClickListner for item in the list

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    startActivity(new Intent(this,destination.class));

}
```